# setting a lengthy text in textblock with fixed width in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, textblock

I have grid on canvas background which can be seen in the picture. On the 1st row, I want to label the columns. I have used TextBlock for that purpose. But when the number of characters are increased I am unable to see the whole content of the TextBlock.e.g When the content is 9990, I can see it but in very next label the content is 10020 which is having more characters. I am able to see only 1002. The rectangle size is 30 which is drawing grid. TextBlock Width is 27 and Margin of TextBlock is 3.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM0m0.png)I do not want to change the font size.

```
 <Canvas  x:Name="back_canvas"  Height="12000"  Width="{Binding  CanvasWidth , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0,0,10,0"   >
                <Canvas.Background>
                        <DrawingBrush TileMode="Tile" Viewport="0,0,30,30"  ViewportUnits="Absolute"> 

                            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,30,30"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                        <Pen Brush="Gray" Thickness="1"/>
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        </DrawingBrush>
                    </Canvas.Background>


                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeAxis}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="horizontalLabels" Orientation="Horizontal"  />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Margin="0,0,3,0"    Width="27"  Background="Red" Height="Auto"  >

                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: could you share your xaml code

Comment: I have shared the code. Please have a look at it.

Comment: did you check TextWrapping="Wrap" in textblock

Comment: Yes, I have checked that. It moves some digits to the next line.

Comment: could share a picture about how it should look like

Comment: https://imgur.com/a3AKbPx
This is the current output while using TextWrapping= Wrap.  I want to see in same line

Comment: So you want the TextBlocks to get bigger to fit the numbers?

Comment: @IDarkCoder I think they want the numbers to fit on one line without changing the size of the container or the size of the text.

Comment: You would need to either, increase the size of the container or reduce the size of the font. If you try to force the text to be written in that size it will overlap onto the next container which would be much worse.

One final option would be to try a different font which was smaller naturally without reducing the actual font size

Comment: @Darnold like Martin Grundy said, that doesn't seem possible/doesn't seem like a good idea...

Comment: @IDarkCoder I agree, it is not possible without changing some aspect to make it fit. I would choose to change the font size first if you have size limitations on the canvas. then create an on hover that would expand the box to view the data if desired.

Comment: @Darnold You could of course also set the `TextTrimming` of the `TextBlock` to `CharacterEllipsis` to indicate that some part is cut off and add a tooltip with the full string.

Comment: @IDarkCoder I have to admit, your solution would be much more elegant.

Comment: @Darnold I included it as an answer, hoping it will help OP.

Comment: It is working smoothly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers that helped you the most :) Glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

As I already mentioned in a comment to the question you could set the `TextTrimming` of the `TextBlock` to `CharacterEllipsis` to indicate that some part is cut off and add a tooltip with the full string.

This would look something like this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" ToolTip="{Binding}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0,0,3,0" Width="27" Background="Red" Height="Auto"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This should change large numbers like `10020` from `| 1002 |` to something like `| 100... |` with a tooltip that says `10020`